# Unable to change ownership of authorized_keys - Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, ssh

I am following these steps in setting up a public/private key set on my server:

**Modify the permissions on the public key by entering the following commands, one by one, on your Linode. Replace example_user with your username.**

```
chown -R example_user:example_user .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

But when i do the first line

```
chown -R david:david .ssh
```

I get the error message:

```
 changing ownership of '.ssh/authorized_keys': Operation not permitted
```

I have followed the steps of the guide, except the fact I am using windows so I had to use windows scr to upload the public key rather than the unix command line.

Here are the file information bits:

```
  File: `.ssh/authorized_keys'
  Size: 294             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: EDITED OUT    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-03-17 16:32:06.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2013-03-17 16:32:06.000000000 +0000
Change: 2013-03-17 19:06:14.000000000 +0000
```

Comment: What type of filesystem is your `.ssh` folder on?  Does the filesystem support ownership?  Some don't, (e.g. fat, some network fs, etc).

Comment: Why use the root account to administer the files of an ordinary user? If you instead use the david account for file transfer as well as login there will be no need to chown any files.

Comment: File owner is root:
Uid: ( 0/ root) Gid: ( 0/ root)
Try to do sudo chmod as already mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you don't have permissions to change ownership of that file.  My guess, whatever filesystem you transferred the file from has different kind of privileges that didn't get transferred correctly, and just ended up owning the document to root.  Try the same chown command again with `sudo` (as in, `sudo chown -R david:david /path/to/.ssh`).  Whenever using a command with `sudo`, it is best practice to use the absolute path (e.g., `/home/david/.ssh`) instead of the relative path ( `./.ssh` ).

Comment: I tried that and it says, sudo command not found. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Become root using `su -`, then try the command again.

Answer (score 1):

For my case:
I tried
`lsattr authorized_keys`
and it results
`-----a-------e-- authorized_keys`.
The *a* here means append-only.

Use `chattr -a authorized_keys` to remove the *a* to make it normal.

Comment: This answer ultimately led me to my resolution, lsattr indicated 'i' which was immutable, and the file couldn't be changed. I had to run `chattr -i authorized_keys` in order to be able to make it mutable again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`su -c "chown david:david ~david/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

at this point you will be asked the password for root and hopefully you know the root password for this machine. Otherwise, you have steep hill to climb ahead of you, in the lack of sudo.

Answer (score 0):

A.D.2020 - I had similar issue with changing permissions and ownership of .ssh 
I couldn't push my rsa key to github.

With a little help of previous answers I sorted it out:

```
sudo chown -R user:user .ssh | chmod 700 .ssh | chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

After that:

~/.ssh `-ls -la`

```
git push -u origin master
```

and it's works :)